# How to set a Fieldset for a custom table in magento2

Tags: magento2

I need to set a fieldset like below for a custom table `pos_agent`

customer fieldset xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
<scope id="global">
    <fieldset id="customer_account">
        <field name="prefix">
            <aspect name="create" />
            <aspect name="update" />
            <aspect name="name" />
        </field>
        <field name="firstname">
            <aspect name="create" />
            <aspect name="update" />
            <aspect name="name" />
        </field>
        <field name="middlename">
            <aspect name="create" />
            <aspect name="update" />
            <aspect name="name" />
        </field>
        <field name="lastname">
            <aspect name="create" />
            <aspect name="update" />
            <aspect name="name" />
        </field>
        <field name="suffix">
            <aspect name="create" />
            <aspect name="update" />
            <aspect name="name" />
        </field>
        <field name="email">
            <aspect name="create" />
            <aspect name="update" />
        </field>
        <field name="password">
            <aspect name="create" />
        </field>
        <field name="confirmation">
            <aspect name="create" />
        </field>
        <field name="dob">
            <aspect name="create" />
            <aspect name="update" />
        </field>
        <field name="taxvat">
            <aspect name="create" />
            <aspect name="update" />
        </field>
        <field name="gender">
            <aspect name="create" />
            <aspect name="update" />
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="customer_address">
        <field name="vat_id">
            <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_is_valid">
            <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_id">
            <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_date">
            <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_success">
            <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="sales_convert_order_address">
        <field name="vat_id">
            <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_is_valid">
            <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_id">
            <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_date">
            <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_success">
            <aspect name="to_quote_address" />
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_address">
        <field name="vat_id">
            <aspect name="to_order_address" />
            <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_is_valid">
            <aspect name="to_order_address" />
            <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_id">
            <aspect name="to_order_address" />
            <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_date">
            <aspect name="to_order_address" />
            <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_success">
            <aspect name="to_order_address" />
            <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="sales_copy_order_billing_address">
        <field name="vat_id">
            <aspect name="to_order" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_is_valid">
            <aspect name="to_order" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_id">
            <aspect name="to_order" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_date">
            <aspect name="to_order" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_success">
            <aspect name="to_order" />
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="order_address">
        <field name="vat_id">
            <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_is_valid">
            <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_id">
            <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_date">
            <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
        </field>
        <field name="vat_request_success">
            <aspect name="to_customer_address" />
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</scope>
```

This is a fieldset.xml in module-customer/etc, I think this xml layout file is used for the name request from front end.

usage of the above xml is here,

```
$customerAccount = $this->_fieldsetConfig->getFieldset('customer_account');
    foreach ($customerAccount as $code => $field) {
        if (isset($field['name'])) {
            $fields[$code] = $code;

        }
    }
```

i had tried same like this for my custom table  but not works. Please anyone help me to create a fieldset with a layout xml file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below `fieldset.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Object/etc/fieldset.xsd">
<scope id="global">
    <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote">
        <field name="custom_fieldset">
            <aspect name="to_order" />
        </field>
    </fieldset>        
    <fieldset id="quote_convert_item">
        <field name="custom_sku">
            <aspect name="to_order_item" />
        </field>
    </fieldset>         
    <fieldset id="sales_convert_order">
        <field name="custom_fieldset">
            <aspect name="to_quote" />
            <aspect name="to_invoice" />
            <aspect name="to_shipment" />
            <aspect name="to_cm" />
        </field>
    </fieldset>        
    <fieldset id="sales_convert_order_item">
        <field name="custom_sku">
            <aspect name="to_quote_item" />
            <aspect name="to_invoice_item" />
            <aspect name="to_shipment_item" />
            <aspect name="to_cm_item" />
        </field>            
    </fieldset>
</scope>
```